# can i use authlogic for two diff model? in a single rails project

Tags: authlogic

I want to use authlogic gem for two diff model in my rails app.

I have two models User and Account in both model i want to use authlogic.

is this possible? how?

plz help?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer after experimenting lot with authlogic.

The answer is NO you can't. We can use authlogic gem only for one model in app. And default

model for authlogic is User model.